# How did Jerusalem function as an ancient city without a major water source?

Tags: ancient-history, jerusalem

Jerusalem seems to be an exception to the rule that all ancient cities must either be on a river or freshwater lake.

First settlement is [estimated](https://www.history.com/topics/ancient-middle-east/history-of-jerusalem) at 3500 BC.

The nearest major river as far as I can tell from maps seems to be the Jordan River, at ~12mi.

Comment: This seems to be answered by the Wikipedia article on the [History of Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Jerusalem).  Questions answered by a simple Google search or to be found in a Wikipedia page are [off-topic](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on History:SE.  You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 4):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gihon_Spring), which is citing Easton's Bible Dictionary, The Gihon Spring was

> a reliable water source that made human settlement possible in ancient Jerusalem – the spring was not only used for drinking water, but also initially for irrigation of gardens.